# Collection with generic and non-generic UnityEvents

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on some project in Unity. I have:

```
[Serializable]
public class ItemAction
{
    [SerializeField]
    private UnityEvent unityEvent;

    public void Perform()
    {
        unityEvent.Invoke();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class ItemAction<T>
{
    [SerializeField]
    private UnityEvent<T> unityEvent;

    public void Perform(T parameter)
    {
        unityEvent.Invoke(parameter);
    }
}
```

Also I have this class:

```
public abstract class Item : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float weight;
    [SerializeField]
    private [collection of item actions] actions;

    public abstract void Use();
    public abstract void Grab(Transform transform);
    public abstract void Drop();
}
```

How to create collection with mixed both generic and non-generic ItemAction instances (so some actions may require some parameters)?
For example:

For unequipped weapons, I can only grab them.
For unequipped medkits, I can grab them or use them immediately.
For triggers/switchers, I can only use them.

I could probably use an empty interface, but I don't think it's good solution...

Answer (score 0):

Like you said you can create a empty interface or just use a collection of objects, because you will have to cast anyways or you skip the ItemAction class and only use the version which has a parameter and pass null for actions which don't require a parameter (not a "nice" solution either, but this is how the WPF framework does it with the ICommand interface, for example)

But there is an other problem, no matter if you use a interface or object list, you will not be able to show them in the editor (unless you create a custom editor), because the editor doesn't show generic classes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to implement the methods in every specific item class inheriting from `Item` (at least, I guess so since you declared those methods `abstract`), 
I'd go with another route, and implement interfaces for every specific action.

For example:

```cs
public interface IItem {
    float Weight { get; set; }
}

public interface IGrabItem : IItem {
    void Grab();
}

public interface IDropItem : IItem {
    void Drop();
}

public interface IUseItem : IItem {
    void Use();
}

public class MedKit : MonoBehaviour, IGrabItem, IUseItem {
    [SerializeField]
    float weight;
    public float Weight {
        get { return weight; }
        set { weight = value; }
    }
    public void Grab() {
        //Your code
    }
    public void Use() {
        //Your code
    }
}
```

and then you can choose to implement the code directly in every specific item class or use some kind of `event` to raise them.

Oh, and btw, if possible, avoid using `UnityEvent` and rely on the standard .NET `event`, it's faster and creates less overhead.